# How to add Ruby 3.0 to node:latest base Docker image

Tags: node.js, ruby, docker

How do I add Ruby 3.0 (or above) to the node:latest base Docker image?

- apt-get doesn't work because the Debian package of Ruby is only 2.7.
- I can't get rvm to work because it doesn't seem to work with sh (only bash)

I suspect there is a higher-level idea I'm missing, but I don't know what it is.  (For example, is there a way to install Ruby 3.0 or above using apt-get?  Is there a way to tell the Docker file to use bash instead of sh?)

(I did find an image that uses Node 14 and Ruby 3.0; but, I'd like to learn what I'm doing wrong here for next time.)

Comment: What application are you running that a Node process invokes a Ruby subprocess?  Can you run these two components in separate containers?

Comment: As an always-available option you can download the source from http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/ and just build it. Quite a straightforward thing if all the dependencies are properly installed.

Comment: Actually it is the other way around:  I have a ruby script that is going to run a node process.  (This is for a PrairieLearn autograder for what it's worth.)

Comment: At this point, I'm more interested in fixing my mental model than anything else.  It doesn't seem like it should be this difficult to install a specific version of both Node and Ruby on a blank linux distribution.  The tools I'm familiar with that make ruby and node installation easy (apt and/or rvm/nvm) don't seem to work in the bare "sh" environment.  Am I looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: @Zack Most of those base images tend to stay as lean as possible (don't include any redundant applications/libraries) because their maintainers keep the production usage in mind 1st of all. And having a version manager (with all its dependencies) just to install and never change a single app version is a kinda overkill. But you can do it (replace sh with bash, install all prerequisites for your version manager and so on and so forth). Or just try to find some fat image that already includes all you need - it might exist as well.